# TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by' error in pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

with no time waste, heading towards the Problem.
I am trying to sort index my data set and get "top_female_ratings" from that mean_ratings DataFrame.
I ran this code:

```
active_titles = ratings_by_title.index[ratings_by_title >= 250]
active_titles[:10]

mean_ratings = mean_ratings.loc[active_titles]
mean_ratings.info()
```

this code gives me this output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1216 entries, 'burbs, The (1989) to eXistenZ (1999)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   F       1216 non-null   float64
 1   M       1216 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 28.5+ KB
```

So, I want to filter and get the top "F" column from above:
I wrote this code:

```
top_female_ratings = mean_ratings.sort_index(ascending=False, by='F')
top_female_ratings[:10]
```

And I got this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0f1195012e3e> in <module>
----> 1 top_female_ratings = mean_ratings.sort_index(ascending=False, by='F')
      2 top_female_ratings[:10]

TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'
```

I didn't understand it.

Comment: are you looking for `sort_values` ?

Answer (score 5):

*if anyone looking for the answer:*

**by** is now removed from **sort_index**, if you following python for data science book, you can use **sort_values** instead of **sort_index** for getting the desired output.

```
top_female_ratings = mean_ratings.sort_values(by='F',ascending=False)
top_female_ratings[:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

DataFrame.sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', sort_remaining=True, ignore_index=False, key=None)

"by" is not a parameter for sort_index function.
One possible way might be

top_female_ratings = mean_ratings['F'].sort_index(ascending=False)
top_female_ratings[:10]

I am begineer please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes, bro, you are right but in another way. 'by' was a parameter of sort_index() years ago but know it is removed. I just removed it from the code and ran the above code without it, and I got my results. I also ran your provided code but your code was giving different results.